# Extending UGC solution

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, ugc

Has anybody tried to extend the UGC to, for example, add answers to the comments or link comments to other comments?

Does anybody know if this is possible with the usual extensions of Tridion, or is somehow more complex?

Answer (score 4):

For examples you gave, using DataExtenders would be probably an easiest solution.

"Usual" data extenders behavior was added in UGC 2013 GA